# Create CSV from SOQL query

Tags: soql, workbench, csv

I'm trying to download the results from my SOQL query as a CSV, but when I choose "Bulk CSV" the resulting file contains *the query itself* and not the result set.

[image: SOQL query -- list view]

List view shows 21k+ records.

[image: SOQL query -- bulk CSV]

It looks like all records were processed, but when I download the file...

```
$ wc -c bulkQuery_request_7503k00000PDhGSAA1_7513k00000UoYmsAAF.txt
51 bulkQuery_request_7503k00000PDhGSAA1_7513k00000UoYmsAAF.txt
$ cat $_; echo
select X3LA__c, Name, Id from Account order by Name
$
```

I get the query instead of the results. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be a misinterpretation of the UI.

You need to click on the download icon

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that was it! That's pretty non-intuitive, at least to me.

Comment: Let's just say you weren't the only one misled:-)